# I'm having trouble removing the white border on v-expansion-panels when the header is clicked to open. The border is only in the animation

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

v-expansion-panels when the header is clicked lights up the panel background with a white border. I have an image as my background for the v-expansion-panel background and I don't want to highlight the edge of the component. How can I turn this off?

Comment: Making it a dark color would be fine too but using dark and light from the api props had no effect

Comment: also box-shadow and -webkit-box-shadow didn't work. the bottom white line turns black but the top left and right are still white with box-shadow: none

Comment: Are you sure you're not talking about the `box-shadow` on `.v-expansion-panel:before`?

Comment: I'm not sure. but I tried to set it to none and it didn't work. also ::before. and I tried active as well. It's something in the animation. there is actually a black border that appears too